# How do you include in an XPage a CSS file that you imported/copied via package explorer?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I imported a bunch of files via the package explorer e.g. images, stylesheets. Now I want to use them in an XPage.

How can I include them e.g. a stylesheet? If I add them via Resources what URL should I use?

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to store files in a NSF:

First you could move them in the folder structure *Resources/* and then in the appropriate subfolder. In this case the files would be available in the Database perspective (If you don't want to sort them, just put them in the *Resources/Files* folder). Or you can just add them in the *WebContent* folder.

In both cases you can access them directly via *xp:this.resources* definition or with the url *http://example.com/yourdb.nsf/style.css*.

**EDIT:**
You can add your ressources in other folders too. If you add them f.e. in a folder names *src* you can access them like this: *http://example.com/yourdb.nsf/src/style.css*. And this is the way to add them as resource:

```
<xp:this.resources>
   <xp:styleSheet href="/src/test.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```